short-name "kong:3.6" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined
Хочу установить kubernetes-dashboard через helm:
helm upgrade --install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --create-namespace --namespace kubernetes-dashboard

После смотрю статус подов:
kubectl get pods -n kubernetes-dashboard

Вижу, что pod

kubernetes-dashboard-kong-57d45c4f69-qfr8r " 0/1     Init:ImageInspectError "

Делаю:
kubectl describe pods kubernetes-dashboard-kong-57d45c4f69-qfr8r -n kubernetes-dashboard

Вижу ошибку:

kubelet  Failed to inspect image "kong:3.6": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = short-name "kong:3.6" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"

Нагуглил, что нужно добавить репозиторий, из которого я хочу спулить этот пакет, в unqualified-search-registries в /etc/containers/registries.conf, либо добавить алиас в файл /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf ("kong" = "docker.io/kong", не уверен что правильно).
Однако это не работало.
Решил сделать:
kubectl edit pods kubernetes-dashboard-kong-57d45c4f69-qfr8r -n kubernetes-dashboard

В spec.image было указано kong:3.6.
Попробовал сделать:
crictl pull kong:3.6

(насколько я понял, crictl также использует registries.conf) - получаю такую же ошибку:

FATA[0000] pulling image: short-name "kong:3.6" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"

Но если я сделаю:
crictl pull docker.io/kong:3.6

образ спулится.
Как изменить /etc/containers/registries.conf, чтобы под сам спулил нужный ему образ?

command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sleep 180']

по умолчанию контейнер без процессов завершается, нужно задать ему процесс

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
